# How to get the current hibernate NamingStrategy?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using my custom `NamingStrategy` by set `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy` to `properties`.

I want to use it to write a `NativeQuery`, in which I must know the actual table name instead of the classname of the entity.

Is there any good idea to fetch the actual `NamingStrategy` on runtime?

Comment: Nop ! 
If you write an `NativeQuery` it 100% `SQL`, so write SQL.

Comment: @Zorglube Thanks for your comment but I'm not sure what you mean. Is it possible to get the actual table name from a class with `@Entity` annotation. Is this possible, or not?

Comment: If your entity contain an `@Table` annotation, yes you can get the table name throught some introspection.

Comment: But if you don't know the table name, maybe use an `JPQL` query is better.

Comment: I just want to use some native function (force index) which is not currently supported by the driver. If you have some idea to acquire the table name on runtime, could you tell me, please?

Comment: You can force the table name through `@Table`